# WooCommerce Subscriptions switch subscription

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, subscriptions

i'm using WooCommerce and Subscriptions. Users can buy a box and select size, delivery cycle and color. If the user want to change its subscription they must go through the entire order process again. Is there a way to simplify this process, for example by offering dropdowns for the different properties in his account area?

Best Regards
Manuel

Answer (score 0):

Woo Subscriptions has full switching functionality, but you have to have planned ahead and prepared all of your options as either variations or as a grouped product.

Here's the docs: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/switching-guide/